# php how to wrap a very long word that has no spaces

Tags: php, css, string, break, cpu-word

I have a problem with wrapping a really long string in my php site. If a user enters a really long string with no whitespaces it breaks the design. For example: "DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD" i want a way to break the word so it does not break the design. Problem only occurs if the string has no whitespaces between characters.
How it looks with normal text: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9L1Bi.jpg

How it looks with a long string with no spaces: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIoht.jpg

I have tried using the css word-wrap property, but it does not solve the problem.

Comment: research `strpos` and `strstr`

Comment: This is a css issue and not php.

Comment: What @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs said. Or `if(strlen($string) > 100))....` either that or some css related stuff. [This](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/prevent-long-urls-from-breaking-out-of-container/) may help you.

Comment: As @steven35 said, this is CSS. Don't try and use PHP. That's just messy. Read this: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_word-break

Comment: Might help > [PHP wordwrap function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php)

Comment: Did you try `word-break: break-all;`?

Comment: @Mr.Blue I never even knew that function existed!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use CSS. Don't complicate things...

```css
.rectangle {
    width: 200px;
    background: red;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class="rectangle">
    <p>DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD</p>
</div>
```

You can read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp).

The word break property will just break any words that go over the edge of the container.

---

After reading some of the comments; I thought I'd add a PHP version.

```php
<?php
$sentence = 'DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD';
$wrapped = wordwrap($sentence, 17, "\n", true);
?>
<style>
    .rectangle {
        width: 200px;
        background: red;
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }
</style>
<div class="rectangle">
    <p><?= $wrapped; ?></p>
</div>
```

Fiddles:

- [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/gWspS)
- [WTools.io](https://wtools.io/php-sandbox/oX)

There are many disadvantages of this method, namely, the fact that you need to know the width of the container and the width of your characters to calculate the breakpoint; then, if you had a responsive website, this would still be broken.

For something like this please use the CSS approach. I only include this way just for completeness.